# UIKeyCommands not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikeycommand

I'm trying to add custom shortcuts for iPad to my app. However, with the code below I can't get to see them working. When I press the command key I get the discovery modal, but when I then press command+f nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

```
#pragma mark - UIResponder

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

- (NSArray *)keyCommands {
    return @[
         [UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:@"f" modifierFlags:0 action:@selector(backspacePressed:) discoverabilityTitle:@"New message"]
    ];
}

- (void)backspacePressed:(UIKeyCommand *)command {
    NSLog(@"Backspace key was pressed");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that, in order for me to be able to register cmd+f, I needed to change the `modifierFlags` from `0` to `UIKeyModifierCommand`.

```
[UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:@"f" modifierFlags:UIKeyModifierCommand action:@selector(backspacePressed:) discoverabilityTitle:@"New message"]
```